# jquery-ui accordion: adding rows without destroying and recreating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I have a jquery accordion which I want to add rows to.  I can accomplish this by calling .accordion("destroy"), adding the needed `<h3></h3><div>`... bit and then calling .accordion() again, but this destroys the state and closes any dividers which are open.

Is it possible to add rows to the accordion without destroy and recreating it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible.  jQuery should add an "add" method to accordion like they have for tabs:

```
//save state
var state = $("#accordion").accordion( "option", "active" );
//add accordion item, destroy then re-create
$("#accordion").append("<h3></h3><div/>").accordion("destroy").accordion();
//set state
$("#accordion").accordion( "option", "active", state );
```

Wrap it in a nice method, extend accordion, submit a patch, etc.  I didn't test this but it should work.  You might have to adjust the state value if the tab was inserted before the active accordion item, instead of appended to the end.

Comment: There's a [jQuery UI feature request](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4672) open for this, and while it's two years old, it's seen some activity in the past couple weeks.  Not out in time for me to use it, but if anyone else stumbles across this it might be worth a look.  Cheers!