# How to stop a jQuery accordion change event when recreating it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have three different accordions in three different dom elements, when I move one accordion section to another accordion section programmatically on a click of move button, I'm recreating all the accordions on the page. I want the selected accordion to be opened/expanded in the moved accordion. But the moved accordion is sometimes collapsed and other times expanded. I think this is happening because after recreating the accordion, it fires the change event and becomes collapsed.

Can any one suggest a solution how to stop that accordion change event after recreating the accordion. I'm already using the suggestion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008243/jquery-ui-accordion-adding-rows-without-destroying-and-recreating)

Answer (score 1):

Store the accordion options in a variable so you can use it over and over again.
Then, when you destroy the accordion, set which pane you want open/active (integer):

```
accord_options.active = 3; // This is the number value of the accordion pane you want open. Accordion panes start at 0.
$selector.accordion('destroy').accordion(accord_options);
```

If you need further control over when the accordion fires, you can use an empty event in the accordion options:

```
accord_options = {
    event: '',
    ...
```

Then create a function to handle accordion clicks:

```
$('#accordion_1 h3').click(function()
{
    if (something_happens)
    {
        // we don't want the accordion to activate here
        return false;
    }

    // to activate an accordion pane:
    $selector.accordion('activate', $('#accordion_1 h3').index(this));

    return false;
}
```

Add your own code to the above click method to handle whether or not you want an accordion pane to activate.